# No repetir clave en diccionario de python

Tags: python

tengo un ejercicio terminado a falta de solucionar el último apartado que pide que no se repitan los nombres de los alumnos, el formato del diccionario es el siguiente {**"nombre_alumno"**,{**"asignatura"**, **nota**}},¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
continuar = True
alumnos = {}    
n_alumnos = int(input("Introduce cantidad de alumnos: "))
while len(alumnos)<n_alumnos:
    nombre = input("Nombre del alumno: ")
    notas = {}
    for m in alumnos:        
        if m==nombre:
            print("no debes poner nombres iguales")
            break
          
    while True:
        asignatura = input("Nombre asignatura: ")
        nota = int(input("nota: "))
        notas[asignatura] = nota
        continuar = input("¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): ")
        if continuar == "si":
            continue
        elif continuar != "si":
            break  
    alumnos[nombre] = notas
     
    print(alumnos)
for i,a in alumnos.items():
    print(i)
    acumulador = 0
    for u,y in a.items():
        acumulador = acumulador + y
print("su nota media es: ",acumulador/len(a))
```

Comment: Para ver si un nombre ya estaba en un diccionario no necesitas iterar. Puedes hacer `if m in alumnos` que es mucho más eficiente. Por otro lado ¿qué es lo que te falla en el código que has puesto? Aparentemente ya estás verificando si el alumno era repetido (aunque puede hacerse más eficiente como acabo de decirte)

Comment: El código no falla, lo que quiero es que si el nombre introducido está ya en el diccionario te pida otro, lo que hace mi programa es continuar el flujo del mismo

Comment: Pues tras leer el nombre puedes poner `if nombre in alumnos: print("Ya estaba"); continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien te dice @abulafia simplemente checkeando la existencia de la cadena dentro del diccionario sería suficiente, pero me he tomado la libertad creativa de modificar un poco tu código para hacerlo más legible y entendible.

*EDIT: Despues de leer tu comentario arriba necesitas volver a introducir el nombre si ya existe y continuar. He hecho una pequeña modificación a mi respuesta para que insista en un nombre nuevo si ya existe.*

```
alumnos = {}
n_alumnos = int(input("Introduce cantidad de alumnos: "))
for _ in range(n_alumnos):
    nombre = input("Nombre del alumno: ")
    notas = {}

    while True:
        nombre = input("Nombre del alumno: ")
        if nombre not in alumnos:
            break
        else:
            print("No puedes poner nombres iguales")

    while True:
        asignatura = input("Nombre asignatura: ")
        nota = int(input("Nota: "))
        notas[asignatura] = nota
        alumnos[nombre] = notas
        continuar = input("¿Desea continuar añadiendo asignaturas?(si/no): ")
        if continuar.lower() not in ("si", "s"):
            break

    print(f"{alumnos}")

for nombre, asignaturas in alumnos.items():
    nota_media = sum(asignaturas.values()) / len(asignaturas.values())
    print(f"{nombre} - su nota media es: {nota_media}")
```

En las primeras lineas tienes varias cosas:

- La variable `continuar` no es necesario inicializarla puesto que más adelante sobrescribes su valor
- Como ya sabes cuantos alumnos vas a ingresar no hace falta un bucle `while` evaluando el tamaño del diccionario, con un bucle for por el rango de alumnos es suficiente (y preferible).
- Hay pocas razones por las que un bucle `while` es preferible a un `for` o incluso a los propios métodos que tienen los iterables.

La linea que buscas está en

```
if nombre not in alumnos:
    break
```

... que comprueba si la cadena que acabas de introducir no existe como clave en el diccionario y rompe ese bucle.

Después viene la parte de la variable `continuar`. Si la cadena no es un "si" o una "s" entonces se rompe el bucle. El método `lower()` devuelve el texto en minusculas.

```
if continuar.lower() not in ("si","s"):
    break
```

Por último a la hora de calcular la nota média es más facil iterar sobre todas las claves del diccionario y desempaquetar clave y valor (que los valores son otro diccionario) en las variables `nombre` y `asignaturas` para nuevamente sumar todos los valores del diccionario `asignaturas` y dividir por su longitud para sacar la media aritmética. Finalmente imprimes por cada nombre su nota media y ya está.

```
for nombre, asignaturas in alumnos.items():
    nota_media = sum(asignaturas.values()) / len(asignaturas.values())
    print(f"{nombre} - su nota media es: {nota_media}")
```

Espero que te haya aclarado un poco la forma con la que se escribe código en python. Muchas cosas repetitivas ya están pensadas en forma de métodos ya prefabricados.

Verás tambien que he usado `f-strings` que son una forma más conveniente y legible de imprimir mensajes con variables. Es tan sencillo como anteponer `f` a una cadena y usar `{variable}` para imprimir esa variable en el sitio que quieras.

Un saludo

Comment: esto `if continuar not in "si":` está mal. Si introduces `s`, `i` o `si` entonces no parará (al menos que eso quieras). Lo correcto es `if continuar.lower() in ["no","n"]: break`

Comment: Tienes razón en lo de la 'i' pero considero 'si' y 's' como opciones correctas. Solo quiero parar cuando no sea "si" o "s". Edito la respuesta para añadir la tupla y evitar la 'i' y el método lower. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: de nada, siempre es bueno evitar case insensitive :D